# Returning value from inside Runnable

Tags: android, runnable, android-room

I am using Android Room, I have tried to build a utility method where I retrieve values from the Database. The issue I am having is trying to pass the values back from inside the Runnable which is being executed asynchronously.

```
public static List<Genre> getAll(final Context context){
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(context.getApplicationContext());
            db.genreDao().getAll();
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

What methods do I have to pass this value back but still run in 'not' on the Main Thread?

Comment: You cannot because it's `Async`. `getAll` method finish right after calling `execute` and `return null`. The task run in another thread. Your options are to make your task become synchronous, or use listener pattern to get the value in different callbacks

Comment: Perhaps listener pattern is the way to go, I will give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can't return a value asynchronously. And I would advise against using static utility methods for working with the db. Also, AsyncTasks are cumbersome to use. Another option is Rx. For example:

```
@Dao
public interface GenreDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Genre")
    List<Genre> getAll();
}

public class GenreRepository {
    //...

    @WorkerThread
    public List<Genre> getAll() {
        //Any other source management logic could be placed here, i.e. retrieving from cache or network
        return genreDao.getAll();
    }
}

public class GenreInteractor {
    //...

    public Single<List<Genre>> getAll() {
        return Single
                .fromCallable(genreRepository::getAll)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
}
```

Then you retrieve your genres list like this:

```
genreInteractor.getAll().subscribe(genres -> {});
```

Or if you want your callback to be on main thread:

```
genreInteractor.getAll().observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(genres -> {});
```